# select the last value after a double grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following example

```
timestamp                  mygroup   value   time_agg
2019-02-02 10:00:00.123    A       10      2019-02-02 10:00:00
2019-02-02 10:00:00.124    A       11      2019-02-02 10:00:00
2019-02-02 10:00:00.125    B       100     2019-02-02 10:00:00
2019-02-02 10:00:00.124    B       200     2019-02-02 10:00:00
```

I am trying to essentially "resample" this database.

That is, for each combination of `time_agg` and `mygroup`, I want the row with the latest `timestamp`.

Expected output is:

```
timestamp                  mygroup   value   time_agg
2019-02-02 10:00:00.124    A       11      2019-02-02 10:00:00
2019-02-02 10:00:00.125    B       100     2019-02-02 10:00:00
```

I was able to do this using the DISTINCT ON syntax but this seems quite slow. Is there something better?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(mygroup, time_agg) mygroup, time_agg, timestamp
FROM THISDATA
ORDER BY mygroup, time_agg DESC, timestamp DESC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Postgresql have `GROUP` as a reserved word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON` is usually the *fastest* way to do what you want.

For performance, I recommend an index on `(group, time_agg desc, timestamp desc)`.

Comment: I think the data is indexed by timestamp only